# Why does awk execute both actions?

Tags: awk

When I run the command:

```
awk '/from/ {print $7} /to/ { print $7}' erroMuitoDoido.txt
```

The file is:

```
May 19 04:44:43 server postfix/smtpd[32595]: CDAB515013: client=servidor.dominio.com.br[10.10.10.44]
May 19 04:44:43 server postfix/cleanup[18651]: CDAB515013: message-id=<20120519074443.CDAB515013@servidor2.dominio.com.br>
May 19 04:44:43 server postfix/qmgr[16684]: CDAB515013: from=atendimento@dominio.com.br, size=19590, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 19 04:44:50 server postfix/pipe[32596]: CDAB515013: to=userdestino@dominiodestino.com.br, relay=dovecot, delay=6.2, delays=0.02/6/0/0.14, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
May 19 04:44:50 server postfix/qmgr[16684]: CDAB515013: removed
```

The output is:

```
from=atendimento@dominio.com.br,
from=atendimento@dominio.com.br,
to=userdestino@dominiodestino.com.br,
```

The problem is that the line "from=atendimento@dominio.com.br," occurs twice! How can I fix this?

AWK version: `GNU Awk 4.0.0`
OS: Debian 6, OpenSuse 12.1, CentOS 6.2

Answer (score 7):

```
$ awk '/from=/ {print $7} /to=/ { print $7}' erroMuitoDoido.txt
```

The reason is:

```
from=atendimento@dominio.com.br,
              ^^
              ^^
```

Comment: Even simpler: `/from=/ || /to=/ { print $7 }`

Comment: If someone has `from=` or `to=` in their e-mail address, you'll have the same problem.  Unlikely, but you might as well make it `: from=` and `: to=` to make false positives even less likely.

Answer (score 3):

All actions are executed in order if the input matches the corresponding pattern. If the input matches both patterns, both actions are executed.

If you want to print the field whether it matches one pattern or the other, combine the two:

```
awk '/from/ || /to/ { print $7}' erroMuitoDoido.txt
```

Here you can combine the two expressions into a single regexp match:

```
awk '/from|to/ { print $7}' erroMuitoDoido.txt
```

For what you're doing, you should anchor the match at the beginning of the field, as you probably don't want to match email addresses that happen to contain the substring `from` or `to`:

```
awk '$7 ~ /^(from|to)=/ { print $7}' erroMuitoDoido.txt
```

If you want different treatment, with this more precise matching, you can use separate actions since these patterns don't overlap.

```
awk '$7 ~ /^from=/ { … } $7 ~ /^to=/ { … }' erroMuitoDoido.txt
```

If you want to stop processing further actions and move on to the next line, you can use the `next` keyword.

Comment: You wrote “anchor the match at the beginning of the field”, but still match against `$0`. You probably intended to write `$7~/^(from|to)=/`. As I am not sure that will always be the `$7`, maybe `/ (from|to)=/` would be better.